# restart mongodb docker with auth

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have a mongoDB docker with name `hi_mongo` and id `123456789`
I have some data already stored in the DB. I have stopped it sometime back and restarted with the command:
`docker restart 123456789`

But now I want to restart this docker with authorization enabled. How to do it without making a new mongoDB docker.

What I have tried so far is - enter this mongoDB container using:
`docker exec -it 123456789 /bin/bash`
and tried editing the `/etc/mongo.conf.orig file` and setting the `authorization:'enabled'` thinking that when I restart the docker from host mongod will restart with auth enabled but that is not the case.

Comment: There's a difference between restarting the docker container and the `mongod` process that runs within the container. In order to enable MongoDB auth feature you only need to restart the `mongod` process. See [MongoDB Enable Auth](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) for steps.

Comment: Why don't you want to make a new mongoDB docker container? Removing a container and replacing it with a new one is very quick and easy with docker; we do it all the time for situations like this.

Comment: Adding to what Vince said, `mongodump` and `mongorestore` are super-easy to use.  Install those on the host to grab the data, rebuild the container, and re-import the data.  If you care about the data, then you should have a process to backup and restore anyway.  That said, you should be able to edit the mongo config in the way you suggested and restart the container. Do you actually need to edit `/etc/mongo.conf` though, not `/etc/mongo.conf.orig`  or was that a typo in your question?

Comment: @boyvinall, I tried editing both files `.conf` and `.conf.orig`  and restarting container in both cases doesn't help. Also, the data is quite huge and it is really difficult (though not impossible) to take a backup and restore in a new container. But I was looking for a simpler workaround. And so far I don't have a backup process but will be working on that sooner. Thanks

Comment: @WanBachtiar, the container is just "Mongo Container" so restarting mongod and restarting container serves the same purpose but yeah they are different. 
1. I can restart container but how pass command line arguments to `docker restart 123456789` so that the container restarts with `auth` enabled.
2. Also, what if I enter the container and try restart the `mongo` process with `auth` enabled and exit the bash. But its not happening either.

Comment: @VinceBowdren the data set is huge.

Comment: @atulj If your data set is held entirely within the container, then you have a deep data storage problem; your current difficulties are one symptom of that problem. I recommend you change to a system where your data is persisted outside the container (e.g. by [docker volume mapping](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)) - then you will get the benefit of being able to create and discard containers quickly and easily.

Comment: Ah, it's a little while since I ran this, but maybe mongo isn't actually using the config file by default - see https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/configuration-options/#use-the-configuration-file.  If you're using https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/3.2/Dockerfile then you could probably just edit the /entrypoint.sh script to add --auth.

Comment: Thanks @VinceBowdren for the insight.

Comment: @boyvinall - after entering the mongoDB container with `bash` I found a `/entrypoint.sh` file. Is this the file used up by container whenever I `restart` this mongoDB container? If yes, can you please tell how to edit it to include `--auth` option to it.

Comment: @boyvinall: here is the `/entrypoint.sh` file - [link](http://ideone.com/fvSX3K)

Comment: @atulj could you clarify how do you mount your data ? i.e. outside of the container. Also, are you using this docker file https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/3.2/Dockerfile ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar now I `mongodump`ed the data and `mongorestore`d it to host machine. Then created new mongo docker (with `--auth` option and using `/data/db:/data/db` option for docker volume mapping as suggested by Vince) and restored the data into it. This is the only workaround as of now. But I am still searching for how it can be implemented within the same container.
And I am not using Dockerfile for now.

Answer (score 0):

Would be able to enable auth by modifying the entrypoint.sh in container. Try below steps:

1) docker exec -it yourcontainer bash

2) find out the mongo configs in your run. it is probably just exec mongod. but for safety, find it out first.

`sed -i 's/exec "$@"/echo "new entrypoint $@" > \/tmp\/echo.txt/g' entrypoint.sh`

stop and start container again. attach to container and check /tmp/echo.txt.

3) replace `exec "$@"` in entrypoint.sh with like `exec mongod --auth`.

4) restart the container, mongod should run with auth enabled.

You should really consider to store the data in a volume instead inside the container.

Answer (score -1):

I am using MongoDB 3.4 and It looks fine.
What I did is that

- Stop your running container. ( docker stop your_container_name )
- db.createUser({"user":"admin","pwd":"password","roles":[ {role:"root",db:"admin"}]});
- Edit your mongodb config. ( in my case /etc/mongod.conf )
- Restart your container. ( docker restart your_container_name)

When you tried to create new user after login then you will get folowing an error.

> db.createUser({"user":"demo","pwd":"password","roles":[
>   {role:"read",db:"admin"}]}); 2016-12-24T14:17:43.949+0000 E QUERY
>   [main] Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to execute
>   command { createUser: "demo", pw d: "xxx", roles: [ { role: "read",
>   db: "admin" } ], digestPassword: false, writeConcern: { w: "majority",
>   wtimeout: 300000.0 } } :
>   _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13 DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1290:15

Hope this helps you.

Comment: If docker container is stopped then how can we execute `db.createUser()` command ?